# Talend Open Studio - tSendMail - HTML script doesn't working

Tags: html, talend

I will give you a little background before explaining my concern, my Talend job creates a table with two columns, a first column which contains the email addresses of the recipients and another column which contains names. The goal is to send each row of the first column the information of the second column in a but via tSendMail. This part works fine. What doesn't work is part of the HTML I'm trying to put together. The objective is in the mail, to insert in an HTML list, the people in the second column via an HTML script, when I do the tests outside of talend, it works correctly. However when I try to do the same thing on Talend side, it doesn't work anymore. So I wanted to know if it is possible to implement HTML scripts in Talend or not. Here is the HTML code that works outside of Talend:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8"/>
  </head>
  
  <body>
     <h1 style="font-size:18.0pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;color:#D05C12;">List of handlers: </h1>
     <ul id="directors"></ul>
    
     <script>
       // The variable containing the comma separated list
       var lst_directors = "director1,director2,director3,director4";
      
       // Split the variable into a list using the comma as a separator
       var listItems = lst_directors.split(',');
      
       //Go through the list and add each item to the HTML list
       listItems.forEach(function(item) {
       var li = document. createElement('li');
       li.textContent = item;
       document.getElementById('directors').appendChild(li);
       });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Talend HTML5 code that I tried to implement that works except the script part:

```
"<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=UTF8\">
  </head>
  
  <body>
<h1 style=\"font-size:18.0pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;color:#D05C12;\">List of handlers: </h1>
     <ul id=\"directors\"></ul>
    
     <script>
       // The variable containing the comma separated list
       var lst_directors = \"director1,director2,director3,director4\";
      
       // Split the variable into a list using the comma as a separator
       var listItems = lst_directors.split(\',\');
      
       //Go through the list and add each item to the HTML list
       listItems.forEach(function(item) {
       var li = document. createElement(\'li\');
       li.textContent = item;
       document.getElementById(\'directors\').appendChild(li);
       });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>"
```

Comment: You should just build the HTML in Talend via the tJavaxxx components.